# Why won't this clearInterval work?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a race where two images move to the right a random number of px's but they won't stop with the clear interval, the alert "stop" works. I'm using a red and green picture with changing z-indexes like a stoplight for the user to start and stop the race.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ship = 0;
var ufo = 0;

function random()
{

    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
    var rand2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);

    ship = ship + rand;
    ufo = ufo + rand2;

    document.getElementById("ufo").style.left = ufo + 'px';
    document.getElementById("spaceship").style.left = ship + 'px';


}

function start()
{
    if(document.getElementById("red").style.zIndex == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("red").style.zIndex = "0";
        alert("go");
        var timer = setInterval(function() {random()},1000);    

    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("green").style.zIndex = "0";
        document.getElementById("red").style.zIndex = "1";
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert("stop");


    }

}

</script>
```

Comment: Besides the `clearInterval`, I guess you didn't fully understand how the `if/else` statement works. Did you?

Answer (score 1):

Because `var timer` only exists within the `if` statement. You need to move it outside of the `start()` function, like this:

```
var timer;

function start()
{
    if(document.getElementById("red").style.zIndex == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("red").style.zIndex = "0";
        alert("go");
        timer = setInterval(function() {random()},1000);    
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("green").style.zIndex = "0";
        document.getElementById("red").style.zIndex = "1";
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert("stop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I could have sworn I tried that before and it still didn't work.

Comment: You don't need to move it out of the function though.